# youtube iframe video progress bar control is missing in non full screen mode for Iphone7 (work properly with Ipad). both safari and google chrome

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have the following code to display youtube iframe in my html5.

```
<iframe width=787.500 height=442.96 src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/q3aCf9bl74M?rel=0&playsinline=1&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" fs="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen = false></iframe>
```

everything is working fine except for the smaller screen (iphone7 and iphone5s) the video progress bar is missing from the screen unless I use full screen mode. Is there any idea to make it appear ? please educate me if you know about this. thank you very much.

Comment: That is expected behavior, unless you add a video directly on HTML then you could control it, iframe it is supposed to work like that.

Comment: @Astrit Thank you very much for your answer. I just wonder this is relate to the screen size or something because it work well on other device. so only way to make this work properly is to embed it without using iframe.